# gnuplot: insert custom xtic label amidst otherwise regular tic intervals

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I'm actually using orgmode to export, so my data is simply in org-table form; that shouldn't matter. It's like so:

```
|  Time | Video | Presentation | Paper |
|-------+-------+--------------+-------|
|     0 |     0 |            0 |     0 |
|    20 |    54 |           63 |    38 |
| 31.25 |    72 |           81 |    44 |
|   33. |    83 |           89 |    49 |
|   34. |    95 |          101 |    54 |
|  36.5 |   102 |          112 |    59 |
```

This is for work, and I'm plotting file downloads over the number of hours since they were made available. An effort was made to point people toward these files at t=28hrs, and I wanted to have a custom tick there matching a vertical line so I could call attention to that and show the downloads before and after the publicity effort. Thus, my gnuplot code looks like so:

```
set title "File Downloads"

set xlabel "Time Since Posting (hrs)"
set xrange [0:40]
set xtics  0,5,40

set ylabel "Downloads"
set yrange [0:125]
set ytics 0,25,125

plot data u 2:3 w l lw 2 lc 1 title 'Video', \
     data u 2:4 w l lw 2 lc 2 title 'Presentation', \
     data u 2:5 w l lw 2 lc 3 title 'Paper
```

I'm aware that one can do something like

```
set xtics ("0" 0, "10" 10, "Event" 30, "40" 40)
```

But I don't really want to do that for all my tics, especially since this will be an ongoing plot and I don't know how far in time I'll track things. Can I specify a regular set of intervals like the above, but then call out a custom tic on top of the axis somehow amidst those pre-defineid tics? This won't work, but for example:

```
set xtics 0,5,40; ("Event" 30)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shown with "Pi" in the documentation:

```
set xtics 0,5,40
set xtics add ("Event" 30)
```

Comment: I was literally just typing my own answer, as I found the same thing. I hunted some more and tried searching various ways and ran into the simple suggestion to just try `gnuplot>help set xtics` where I saw the peculiar "add" command... thanks and foolish me.

Comment: Actually... I have another question for you. Let's say that I do the above at 29 instead of 30. Now I have a tic at 30 and it's overrun by my label at 29. I couldn't find a way to do `set xtics 0,5,25` followed by `set xtics add ("Event" 29)` followed by `set xtics add 35,5,40`. It just takes the second set of numerical interval xtics. How might I space them before and after "Event" as not to have jumbled text?

Comment: @Hendy: By "add", you can only mix 1 generated and any number of explicit ticks. Therefore, in this case, you have to generate the remaining tics in your favourite language (i.e. `seq 35 5 40 | sed 's/\(.*\)/set xtics add ("\1" \1);/'` in shell.

Comment: thanks! the output, then, would be `("0" 0, "5" 5, ... , "Event" 29, "35" 35, ... , "60" 60, "65" 65)` -- is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Hendy: not really. The output is like `set xtics add ("35" 35);
set xtics add ("40" 40);`

Comment: groovy. I think I'd opt for my version, then. If I have to type them all anyway, there's no harm in just specifying all tics individually in parentheses and foregoing the `add` command for each one.